# Installation Problem on Widows 8.1

Tags: usb-installation

I have Windows 8.1. I created a bootable USB, and when I clisk 'Install Ubuntu', all I get is a black screen with a white square. The PC hangs there, and I cannot do or see anything. 
How do I proceed with the installation?

Comment: What is the brand of your USB stick?

Comment: Review this first: http://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it
What brand/model system? Pre-installed Windows, so UEFI?  Be sure to boot installer in UEFI boot mode, then.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen this sort of thing with several attempts of different Linux distros, but with CD/DVD installs. LiveCD would show up fine, but the moment
of install attempt, just seemed to go to blank screen and hang. 
  Take a look into 'boot options'. ACPI can be a problem and if the install
can't configure graphics beyond an initial requirement for LiveCD, just blank screen and hang. You will have to experiment to determine the best combination
for your situation.
  Unfortunately, it may be more challenging if you discover the need for a graphics driver for your card. 
  This is not a solid or complete answer to your question, but it may send you
in a direction getting you further along. Hope it helps.

Comment: I did manage to figure it out eventually. I re-created my bootable USB using Unetbootin (Rather than Universal USB Installer or Win32DiskImager, as seen in some websites. These 2 gave me the problem while installing)

Now I got Ubuntu installed successfully. 

But my first boot after installation failed, it came up with a black screen.

After further research on google, I edited the Grub to use 'nomodeset' and successfull launched the Ubuntu desktop and installed the Nvidia updates as was suggested by Ubuntu.

Next reboot, it fails!

Errorlog: Load Fallback Graphics Driver  <FAIL>
Help please.